# I am reading a csv file using python and i want to get rows which has postive values from the csv file(PYTHON)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am reading a csv file using python and i want to get rows which has postive values from the below csv file.

below is the code that i am trying in python

```
import csv
with open('fa.csv','r') as fa:
    test=csv.reader(fa)
    for i in test:
        if int(i[1])<=31:
            print(i[0],i[1])
fa.close()

testing1.com -1172
testing2.com -1171
testing3.com -1171
testing4.com 250
testing5.com 120
testing6.com 45
testing7.com 39

i am looking for the output

testing6.com 45
testing7.com 39
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. For instance why is 'testing5.com 120' not the output you are looking for. Remember positive means > (strictly greater than) 0.

Answer (score 1):

If i is equal to the url and then the integer you can just do

```
if int(i[1]) >= 0:
    print(i[0], i[1]) #Because every number over 0 is positve
```

The only thing I'm not sure is that you say you don't want 120 and 250 although 120 and 250 are both positive, so this question isn't quite clear

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong bigger than it should be if `int(i[1])>=31:` rather than  `int(i[1])<=31:` and i would change the `31` to  a `0`.